# Migrate app in openshift with "create --from-app" doesn't load my old application [Grails]

Tags: grails, tomcat7, openshift

I have a Grails application in Openshift and I've recently upgraded my plan from free to silver and I need to migrate my application from non scalable to scalable, to do this I used the command rhc create-app  --from-app  app --scaling. After a while the new app is created but when I run it, it doesn't load the app, just the by default tomcat first screen.

**Update**: The logs of the new app show this:

```
==> app-root/logs/haproxy_ctld.log <==
I, [2015-04-18T01:02:28.949500 #163665]  INFO -- : Starting haproxy_ctld
I, [2015-04-18T08:28:39.200616 #496980]  INFO -- : Starting haproxy_ctld

==> app-root/logs/haproxy.log <==
[WARNING] 107/010224 (167630) : config : log format ignored for proxy 'express' since it has
 no log address.
[WARNING] 107/012317 (167630) : Server express/local-gear is DOWN for maintenance.
[ALERT] 107/012317 (167630) : proxy 'express' has no server available!
[WARNING] 107/082838 (496963) : config : log format ignored for proxy 'stats' since it has n
o log address.
[WARNING] 107/082838 (496963) : config : log format ignored for proxy 'express' since it has
 no log address.
[WARNING] 107/082838 (496963) : Server express/local-gear is DOWN, reason: Layer4 connection
 problem, info: "Connection refused", check duration: 0ms. 0 active and 0 backup servers lef
t. 0 sessions active, 0 requeued, 0 remaining in queue.
[ALERT] 107/082838 (496963) : proxy 'express' has no server available!
[WARNING] 107/082851 (496963) : Server express/local-gear is UP, reason: Layer7 check passed
, code: 200, info: "HTTP status check returned code <3C>200<3E>", check duration: 2ms. 1 act
ive and 0 backup servers online. 0 sessions requeued, 0 total in queue.
[WARNING] 107/085928 (496963) : Server express/local-gear is DOWN for maintenance.
[ALERT] 107/085928 (496963) : proxy 'express' has no server available!

==> app-root/logs/jbossews.log <==
Apr 18, 2015 8:28:47 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 3727 ms
Apr 18, 2015 8:59:28 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol pause
INFO: Pausing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-127.7.39.1-8080"]
Apr 18, 2015 8:59:28 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService stopInternal
INFO: Stopping service Catalina
Apr 18, 2015 8:59:28 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol stop
INFO: Stopping ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-127.7.39.1-8080"]
Apr 18, 2015 8:59:28 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol destroy
INFO: Destroying ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-127.7.39.1-8080"]
b
```

Comment: What do the logs say in the new app

Comment: How is your code deployed? Are you committing the code into your git repository? Or uploading a war file?

Comment: Uploading a war file.

Comment: If you are uploading a war file manually to deploy, then it won't work, when you do the backup it takes the files from your git repo, and from your data dir, and any databases you have setup and migrates them.  If you want the backup to work, you would have to commit your war file into git.